# check whether two sentences have same meaning in qt

Tags: qt

I am struggling to create my member function in Qt5 that needs to check if 2 sentences are the same with the words reversed in it. The user needs to put a sentence in a `QInputbox` and it must be reversed. The 2 sentences need to be compared and tell the user if the sentence is reversible. They give an example of a sentence All-for-one and One-for-all that have the same meaning, but 'I am Sam' and 'Sam am I' must return false.

If I look at the examples that they give us I have to compare the sentences and return function true if sentences are synonyms of each other if I'm correct. How do you check if two sentences are synonyms. I don't know where to start.

The function is

```
bool isReversible (QString sentence)
```

I also aready have a function

```
QString wordsReversed (QString sentence)
```

Comment: `return sentenceToTest == wordsReversed(sentenceToTest);` ?

Comment: Sorry, but "All-for-one" and "One-for-all" *don't* have the same meaning. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcMCd520Ae8

Comment: If this is an assignment, this seems a little ridiculous to me. You'd need some sort of AI or a big library of synonyms to make this work. Also as Ilya pointed out, one for all and all for one are not synonyms. Are you sure it's not just about reversing the sentence, in which case `I am Sam` => `Sam am I` would be true?

Comment: I saw that I read the sentence wrongly. All for one and one for all is one sentence not two seperate sentences cant believe I didn't see it. So then the sentence must read the same reversed.

Comment: I see. Makes sense now.